# Azure Query only finding records when run in query explorer

Tags: azure, f#, azure-cosmosdb

I have a query I'm running against my Azure DocumentDb to find users based on username or email:

```
let searchUsers (u : string) (e : string) =
    let ul = u.ToLowerInvariant()
    let el = e.ToLowerInvariant()

    printfn "Search fields are username: %A , email %A" ul el

    let q = query {
        for x in client.CreateDocumentQuery<User>( documentUri(), feed() ) do
        where (x.RecordType = userRecordType && (x.UsernameLowercase = ul || x.EmailLowercase = el))
        select x
    }

    printfn "Query is %A" q.Expression

    Seq.toList q
```

From my print statements, I can get the following output:

```
Search fields are username: "" , email "test@test.com"

Query is https://REDACTED.Where(x => 
    ((x.RecordType == "user") AndAlso 
        ((x.UsernameLowercase == "") OrElse (x.EmailLowercase == "test@test.com"))))
```

This query always returns 0 results.

If I run this query on the Query Explorer in the Azure Portal:

```
SELECT * FROM c
where c.RecordType = "user"
and (
    c.UsernameLowercase = ""
    or 
    c.EmailLowercase = "test@test.com"
)
```

I get the single record that I expect to find.

The only thing I'm setting in my `FeedOptions` object is `EnableCrossPartitionQuery <- true`, which was required for the queries to run at all.

The record itself has a `UsernameLowercase` value of `testaccount`, but setting this in the query I'm running in code doesn't find my record anyways. The fields I am searching on aren't option types, DUs, or anything else special - they're simply strings.

**EDIT**:

I found the issue... and as always, if you can't find the issue where you're looking, then you need to look elsewhere!

In one of the calling functions, I was returning the `async` computation itself, rather than the results of the query.

Comment: Do you get your results if you remove some of `where` conditions in your query? Is that the minimal query that gives you problems?

Comment: If I remove the where clause entirely, I still get no results. Hm. That's weird because I have similar queries checking for duplicate user names...